# When was the date of the appointment of Mohammad as prophet?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, history

I was wondering about the date of the appointment of Prophet Mohammad (**His prophetic mission**).

Do you know when its date is?

Both Sunni and Shia view welcomed. I'd be grateful if you present some **authentic** sources for your responses.

Comment: Hello since you are asking about to different views please ask a separate question for each view. Also please clarify your question

Comment: I've heard that Prophet(pbuh) is considered born Prophet by Shias, is it true, forget about his mission, because Sunnis believe he got prophet-hood at the age of 40..

Answer (score 3):

Sunni view:
At the age of forty years on the authority of ibn 'Abbas:

> Narrated Ibn `Abbas:
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) started receiving the Divine Inspiration at the age of forty. Then he stayed in Mecca for thirteen years, receiving the Divine Revelation. Then he was ordered to migrate and he lived as an Emigrant for ten years and then died at the age of sixty-three (years). (Sahih al-Bukhari a slightly different version on his authority is also available in Sahih al-Bukhari)

and Anas ibn Malik:

> Narrated Anas bin Malik:
> The Prophet (ﷺ) was neither conspicuously tall, nor short; neither, very white, nor tawny. His hair was neither much curled, nor very straight. Allah sent him (as an Apostle) at the age of forty (and after that) he stayed for ten years in Mecca, and for ten more years in Medina. Allah took him unto Him at the age of sixty, and he scarcely had ten white hairs on his head and in his beard. (Sahih al-Bukhari)
>
> Anas b. Malik reported that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) was neither very conspicuously tall nor short-statured, and his color was neither glaringly white nor brown; his hair was neither very curly nor very straight; Allah commissioned him (as a Prophet) when he had reached the age of forty years, and he stayed in Mecca for ten years and for ten years in Medina; Allah took him away when he had just reached the age of sixty, and there had not been twenty white hair in his head and beard. (Sahih Muslim)

Note that Quran also emphasizes on the age of forty years in [46:15](http://quran.com/46/15) so it might have some meaning! (see also https://www.missionislam.com/family/ageforty.html)

> Imam an-Nawawi in his commentary on sahih Muslim said there's consensus about the fact that the Messenger of Allah has been living in Mekka 40 years before his commission and in Medina 10 years the only thing where there is a dispute is the amount of years he stayed in Mekka after his commission and the most correct is 13 years (see for example here). This means his age when he died was 63 years. (See this answer https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/35220/13438)

[Al-Mubarkapury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safiur_Rahman_Mubarakpuri) المباركفوري even calculated an exact date in ar-Raheeq al-Makhtoom:

> فيقول المباركفوري في الرحيق المختوم في تحديد تاريخ البعثة: وبعد النظر والتأمل في القرائن والدلائل يمكن لنا أن نحدد ذلك اليوم بأنه كان يوم الاثنين لإحدى وعشرين مضت من شهر رمضان ليلا، ويوافق 10 أغسطس سنة 610م، وكان عمره صلى الله عليه وسلم إذ ذاك بالضبط أربعين سنة قمرية وستة أشهر و12 يوماً، وذلك نحو 39 سنة شمسية وثلاثة أشهر، و22 يوماً. انتهى.
> ([Islamweb, Fatwa #42006](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/42006))

saying it was on Monday the 21st Ramadan (at night) the equivalent to the August the 10th 610 C.E. and he was at the time 40 -moon- years 6 months and 12 days old and about 39 -sun- years three months and 22 days.

Answer (score 1):

According to the view of Shiite, the date of the appointment of Prophet Muhammad(s) (Prophetic Mission) was the 27th of Rajab, 40th year of elephant (610 C.E.). For instance (as authentic sources of Shiite): Marhum Koleini, Sheikh Sadoogh, and Sheikh Tusi have mentioned its date.

But according to Sunni view: There are some probable dates, such as:
17th, 18th or  24th (of Ramadhan).
Or even according to some narrations : 10th or 12th of Rabi’ul Awwal.

---

**Source(s):**

[www.sibtayn.com](http://www.sibtayn.com/en/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5998:holy-prophet-s-p-b-u-h-appointment-to-prophetic-mission&catid=625&Itemid=705)

[http://rasoolnoor.com](http://rasoolnoor.com/modules.php?name=Maghaleh&pa=showpage2&pid=49)

Comment: Don't shia's believe he(pbuh) was a born prophet???

Comment: "But according to Sunni view:", is it also in the same year i.e. 610 CE????

Comment: What's the meaning of 40th year of elephant (610 C.E.) you wrote?

Comment: As a helpful related link: http://en.wikishia.net/view/%27Am_al-Fil   ________  Good luck