# At what age did Mohammed(PBUH) passed away?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, history, hadith-interpretation, death

At what age did Mohammed(PBUH) passed away ?

According to hadith literature it vary between 60 , 63 and 65. Which is the correct age at which Prophet passed away?

Age of 60

> **Bukhari Volume 7, Book 72, Number 787** : Narrated Anas bin Malik: The
>   Prophet was neither conspicuously tall, nor short; neither, very
>   white, nor tawny.His hair was neither much curled, nor very straight.
>   Allah sent him (as an Messenger)at the age of forty (and after that)
>   he stayed for **ten years in Makkah, and for ten more years in Medina**.
>   Allah took him unto Him at the **age of sixty**, and he scarcely had ten
>   white hairs on his head and in his beard.
>
> **Bukhari Volume 4, Book 56, Number 747**: Narrated Rabia bin Abi
>   Abdur-Rahman: I heard Anas bin Malik describing the Prophet saying,
>   "He was of medium height amongst the people, neither tall nor short;
>   he had a rosy color, neither absolutely white nor deep brown; his hair
>   was neither completely curly nor quite lank. Divine Inspiration was
>   revealed to him when he was forty years old. **He stayed ten years in
>   Makkah receiving the Divine Inspiration, and stayed in Medina for ten
>   more years.** When he expired, he had scarcely twenty white hairs in his
>   head and beard." Rabi'a said, "I saw some of his hairs and it was red.
>   When I asked about that, I was told that it turned red because of
>   scent."
>
> **Bukhari Volume 4, Book 56, Number 748:** Narrated Anas: Allah's
>   Messenger was neither very tall nor short, neither absolutely white
>   nor deep brown. His hair was neither curly nor lank. Allah sent him
>   (as an Messenger) when he was forty years old. **Afterwards he resided
>   in Makkah for ten years and in Medina for ten more year**s. When Allah
>   took him unto Him, there was scarcely twenty white hairs in his head
>   and beard.
>
> **Muslim Book 030, Number 5794**: Anas b. Malik reported that Allah's
>   Messenger (may peace be upon him) was neither very conspicuously tall
>   nor short-statured, and his color was neither glaringly white nor
>   brown; his hair was neither very curly nor very straight; Allah
>   commissioned him (as a Prophet) when he had reached the age of forty
>   years, and **he stayed in Makkah for ten years and for ten years in
>   Medina;** Allah took him away when he had just reached the **age of sixty**,
>   and there had not been twenty white hair in his head and beard.
>
> **Muatta Book 49, Number 49.1.1:** Yahya related to me from Malik that
>   Rabia ibn Abi Abd ar-Rahman heard Anas ibn Malik say, "The Messenger
>   of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, was not excessively
>   tall or short. He was not very pallid nor dark. He did not have curly
>   hair or lank hair. Allah commissioned him at the age of forty. **He
>   stayed in Makka ten years and at Madina for ten years** and Allah the
>   Mighty, the Majestic made him die when **he was sixty**. There were not
>   twenty white hairs in his hair or beard, may Allah bless him and grant
>   him peace."

Age of 63

> **Bukhari Volume 5, Book 58, Number 190:** Narrated Ibn 'Abbas: Allah's
>   Messenger was inspired Divinely at the age of forty. T**hen he stayed in
>   Makkah for thirteen years, and then was ordered to migrate, and he
>   migrated to Medina and stayed there for ten years** and then died.
>
> **Bukhari Volume 5, Book 58, Number 242**: Narrated Ibn Abbas: Allah's
>   Messenger started receiving the Divine Inspiration at the age of
>   forty. Then **he stayed in Makkah for thirteen years, receiving the
>   Divine Revelation. Then he was ordered to migrate and he lived as an
>   Emigrant for ten years** and then died at the **age of sixty-three
>   (years).**

Age of 65

> **Muslim, Book 030, Number 5809**: Ibn 'Abbas reported that Allah's
>   Messenger (may peace be upon him) stayed in **Makkah for fifteen years**
>   (after his advent as a Prophet) and he heard the voice of Gabriel and
>   saw his radiance for seven years but did not see any visible form, and
>   then received revelation for ten years, and he **stayed in Medina for
>   ten years.**
>
> **Muslim, Book 030, Number 5805:** 'Ammar, the freed slave of Banu Hashim,
>   reported: I asked Ibn 'Abbas how old was he when death overtook the
>   Messenger of Allah (may peace be upon him). He said: I little know
>   that such a thing is not known to a man like you who belong to his
>   people. He said: I asked people about it but they differed with me, and
>   I liked to know your opinion about it. He said: Do you know counting?
>   He said: Yes. He then said: Bear this in mind very well that he was
>   commissioned (as a Prophet) at the age of forty, and he **stayed in
>   Makkah for fifteen years**; sometime in peace and sometime in dread, and
>   **(lived) for ten years after his migration to Medina.**

Why is the age 63 accepted rather than 60 or 65? Is it the consensus of the ulema?

Comment: Your question about whether all these hadith should be considered sahih was mostly tangential to the *actual* question about the age of the prophet at death. I have posted that as a separate question here: http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35221/22

Answer (score 3):

[Anas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anas_ibn_Malik) was a young man when the Messenger of Allah passed away and a child of ten years when Muhammad came to Medina, so he couldn't have exactly witnessed how long the Prophet lived in Mekka, but he heard it from others, so here I wouldn't give much for the amount quoted in his hadith this means you can clearly delete or forget about all the quotes about 60 years. As his statement is less exact.

And the ahadith from sahih Muslim don't give an exact amount so we have 63 years as a result. Even if one of them quotes ibn 'Abbas as a clear source of the statement.

Imam an-Nawawi in his commentary on sahih Muslim said there's consensus about the fact that the Messenger of Allah has been living in Mekka 40 years before his commission and in Medina 10 years the only thing where there is a dispute is the amount of years he stayed in Mekka after his commission and the most correct is 13 years (see for example [here](http://hadithportal.com/hadith-sharh-2353-1711&book=2)). This means his age when he died was 63 years.